# React native undefined in not an object evaluation props.route.params.source

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hello I'm a beginner in react native, and I'm trying to get the URI of the video picked from Galerie and use it in another component, I'm testing it with console log but this error is appearing
undefined in not an object evaluation props.route.params.source
this is the page that the video will be picked from Galerie:

```
 import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native'
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera'
import { Audio } from 'expo-av'
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker'
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library'
import * as VideoThumbnails from 'expo-video-thumbnails';

import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/core'
import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons'

import styles from './styles'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'

    
    
    export default function CameraScreen() {
        const [hasCameraPermissions, setHasCameraPermissions] = useState(false)
        const [hasAudioPermissions, setHasAudioPermissions] = useState(false)
        const [hasGalleryPermissions, setHasGalleryPermissions] = useState(false)
    
      
    
        const [cameraRef, setCameraRef] = useState(null)
        const [cameraType, setCameraType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back)
        const [cameraFlash, setCameraFlash] = useState(Camera.Constants.FlashMode.off)
    
        const [isCameraReady, setIsCameraReady] = useState(false)
        const isFocused = useIsFocused()
    
        const navigation = useNavigation()
        useEffect(() => {
            (async () => {
                const cameraStatus = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync()
                setHasCameraPermissions(cameraStatus.status == 'granted')
    
                const audioStatus = await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync()
                setHasAudioPermissions(audioStatus.status == 'granted')
    
                const galleryStatus = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync()
                setHasGalleryPermissions(galleryStatus.status == 'granted')
    
              
            })()
        }, [])
    
    
        const recordVideo = async () => {
            if (cameraRef) {
                try {
                    const options = { maxDuration: 60, quality: Camera.Constants.VideoQuality['480'] }
                    const videoRecordPromise = cameraRef.recordAsync(options)
                    if (videoRecordPromise) {
                        const data = await videoRecordPromise;
                        const source = data.uri
                        /*let sourceThumb = await generateThumbnail(source)*/
                        /*navigation.navigate('savePost', { source, sourceThumb })*/
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.warn(error)
                }
            }
        }
    
        const stopVideo = async () => {
            if (cameraRef) {
                cameraRef.stopRecording()
            }
        }
    
        const pickFromGallery = async () => {
            let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
                mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Videos,
                allowsEditing: true,
                aspect: [16, 9],
                quality: 1
            })
            if (!result.cancelled) {
                let sourceThumb = await generateThumbnail(result.uri)
                navigation.navigate('AddProduct', {source : result.uri})
              
            }
        }
    
       
    
        if (!hasCameraPermissions || !hasAudioPermissions || !hasGalleryPermissions) {
            return (
                <View></View>
            )
        }
    
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {isFocused ?
                    <Camera
                        ref={ref => setCameraRef(ref)}
                        style={styles.camera}
                        ratio={'16:9'}
                        type={cameraType}
                        flashMode={cameraFlash}
                        onCameraReady={() => setIsCameraReady(true)}
                    />
                    : null}
    
                <View style={styles.sideBarContainer}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.sideBarButton}
                        onPress={() => setCameraType(cameraType === Camera.Constants.Type.back ? Camera.Constants.Type.front : Camera.Constants.Type.back)}>
    
                        <Feather name="refresh-ccw" size={24} color={'white'} />
                        <Text style={styles.iconText}>Flip</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
    
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.sideBarButton}
                        onPress={() => setCameraFlash(cameraFlash === Camera.Constants.FlashMode.off ? Camera.Constants.FlashMode.torch : Camera.Constants.FlashMode.off)}>
    
                        <Feather name="zap" size={24} color={'white'} />
                        <Text style={styles.iconText}>Flash</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
    
    
                <View style={styles.bottomBarContainer}>
                    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}></View>
                    <View style={styles.recordButtonContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            disabled={!isCameraReady}
                            onLongPress={() => recordVideo()}
                            onPressOut={() => stopVideo()}
                            style={styles.recordButton}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={() => pickFromGallery()}
                            style={styles.galleryButton}>
                            
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }

and this is the other page where I want to retrieve the video URI:

        import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
    import React from 'react'
    
    export default function AddProductScreen(props) {
       console.log(props.route.prams.source)
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>AddproductScreen</Text>
        </View>
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe is a misspelling? you have console.log(props.route.prams.source) instead of console.log(props.route.params.source)

Comment: omg yes i didn't notice thanks

Comment: We've all been through this!